# Archiving tweets in a database (avoiding duplicates)

Tags: php, mysql, json

i'm going to archive my tweets in a database. but what i've done is written a PHP script which goes and grabs the latest 200 tweets from a user (me) and then will insert them into the database. This PHP script is going to run on a Cron Job but what i'm confused about is how to avoid having duplicate tweets being put into the database. The structure was going to be table: User, then two columns, ID and Tweet. So how would i get the PHP to avoid putting in duplicate tweets that it, say, put in the day before?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you save the Tweet ID and make sure the ID didn't already exist before insering?

Comment: Didn't your JSON tweet data from yesterday contain `"id": 25698023782744064,` - that would seem suitable as primary key to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Don't grab the last 200. You might miss some, or grab way to much. Just use the last id in the api call.

Comment: oh ok, so look at the last tweet_id inserted with PHP then check against JSON results from Twitter API and just store from the last tweet_id onwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the Twitter API provides a unique tweet ID, you can set that field as `UNIQUE` on your database. When you try to insert a tweet which ID is already present, the insertion won't occur.

Comment: Anytime. Don't forget to make sure a failed insertion doesn't rollback the whole transition.

Comment: ahh, how would i do that? Within the SQL query?

Comment: Well, first, make sure all works fine. If it doesn't, I'd blame the PHP's database object access configs, and tweak those.

Comment: Haven't looked at PHP for at least 2 years now :D

Comment: You can either have one transaction per insert (which is dumb), or you can user the `IGNORE` keyword on the insert statement. Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html: «If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.»

Answer (score 1):

You could hash the text of your tweet and add a unique column to your table that holds the hashes.

```
md5($tweettext)
```

Comment: Why hash? Tweets are only 140 characters. You can just compare on the actual tweet and let the database figure out itself what is the best way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is for you to get newest 200 tweets from the server in a php hash. construct and array of their tweet_ids. select from database where these tweet_ids exist. remove the ones that exist in the database from your hash of new tweets and insert the rest in the database.

I had the same problem. First I used twitter since_id and found out that twitter API (since_id) is not working the way I assumed it works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't retreive the last 200. The Twitter api provides ways to retreive tweets from a certain ID. Just save the last id you retreived.